# How can I encrypt my Ubuntu partition?

Tags: dual-boot, encryption, gparted

I have Windows 10 and Ubuntu. I want to know how to encrypt the Ubuntu partition so no malware can jump from windows.

Comment: What made you think that a malware cannot harm an encrypted filesystem?

Comment: I see that you still haven't accepted my answer. I it helped you, which I hope I did, please accept my answer by following the instructions here http://askubuntu.com/help/someone-answers

Answer (score 0):

If the only reason you want to encrypt your Ubuntu partition is because of fear for malware from Windows, then you probably don't want to do it.

It is *almost* impossible for Windows malware to harm Ubuntu as Ubuntu *generally speaking* does not understand EXE files (unless you use Wine).

If you want to encrypt your Ubuntu partition because you fear that Windows malware will corrupt the Ubuntu partition, encryption is not going to solve the problem.